# Question about node performance on listening event of contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, events, nodes

what is the best way to listen new event emitted from contract with smallest delay? Other third party (Infura, Alchemy) is good enough or I have to run a new node ? ( as i know until now, public node on bsc may up to 2s latency for example)

Answer (score 0):

In blockchain blocks are generated in a decentralized way. It takes time to propagate them through the network. Having your own node will not change that. To have a small delay you'll need to run several nodes connected to the more important nodes of the network.

Comment: so why there are a lot of sniper bots can have block-0 functionality ?

Comment: @dang.pm.IT Usually, sniper bots acts on the pending transactions pool, before the transactions are executed into a block. They could use a service like flashbots to group a those transactions with their owns.